# The between and like functions with dates

Tags: oracle, sql-like, between

I ran these two scripts below and they give two different results. The first did not include data for the 30th of April but the latter does. I am using oracle sql. Could someone assist?

```
select distinct * from a where (m_date between'01-MAY-17' AND '30-MAY-17');

select distinct * from a where m_date like '%-MAY-17';
```

Comment: What datatype is `m_date`? If it's a date, beware that you are doing implicit conversions from string to date here. If `'30-MAY-17'` is being correctly converted to a date value, your `between` expression will match any rows where the time is `00:00` (midnight) on 30 May but not any datetime values after that point. If it's a date, don't use `like`. If it's a string, consider converting it to a date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the to_date function and it worked:

select distinct * from a where to_date (m_date) between'01-MAY-17' AND '30-MAY-17'

This produced the same results as with the like clause:

select distinct * from a where m_date like '%-MAY-17'

Comment: Don't use character string functions to do date comparisons. Oracle has built-in support for dates and times which are powerful and will serve you much better in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Your between clause

```
select distinct * from a where to_date (m_date) between'01-MAY-17' AND '30-MAY-17'
```

is the same as saying (pseudo-code)

```
...where to_date (m_date) between '01-may-17 00:00:00' AND '30-may-17 00:00:00'...
```

which excludes and date values on 5/30 where there is any time element other than 12AM in the morning.  (Also, May does have 31 days).

It would be more correct to do the following, assuming m_date is a date data type and assuming you want all values during the month of may.

```
... where m_date >= to_date('01-may-17') and m_date < to_date('01-jun-17')...
```